# iPad2 SDK 4.x custom UIFonts are not showing up in list?

Tags: iphone, custom-font

I added custom fonts by following some instructions suggesting add them to plist.info under the key "Fonts provided by application" and supposedly magic happens and it works.  But, I wrote this snippet to dump the fonts and I do not see my custom fonts, just the existing app fonts.  I put the code in my app-delegate here:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

...

```
    // Snippet to dump the list of fonts in the system.
for (id objFamilyName in [UIFont familyNames]) {
    if ([objFamilyName isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        for(id objFontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:(NSString*)objFamilyName]) {
            if ([objFontName isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
                NSLog(@"%s: %@: %@", __FUNCTION__, objFamilyName, objFontName); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Likewise, if I try to load the named font, it does not have any effect.

My settings look like this (font names are like "**cssbook.ttf**"

[image]

Comment: Did you add the font (.ttf) to your application bundle?

Comment: Just the settings above (I added to my description).  Am I supposed to add to the copy script or anything like that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, load Font Book and check to see exactly what the font name / family is.  then add the actual .ttf file to your application so that it is available to your app at runtime.

Comment: That was the "magic" -- now I can apply them from IB or programmatically!